# How can I set videojs to have a vertical volume slider

Tags: javascript, video.js

I've seen two bits around that purportedly do this, but can't seem to get the results that I want in my player. I just want to toggle the volumeBar to display vertically. I'm using video.js v4.3 and am using the default skin. Everything is working properly, but I can't get the slider to change orientation. I've tried the following:

```
videojs("{{video id}}", {
    "controls": true,
    "autoplay": false,
    "preload": "auto",
    "poster": "{{image}}",
    "width": {{width}},
    "height": {{height}},
    'children': {
      'controlBar': {
        'children': {
          'volumeControl': {
            'children': {
              'volumeBar' : {
                vertical: true
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
}, function(){
  // Do things
});
```

and

```
videojs("{{video id}}", {
    "controls": true,
    "autoplay": false,
    "preload": "auto",
    "poster": "{{image}}",
    "width": {{width}},
    "height": {{height}},
    'volumeBar': {
        'vertical': true
    }
}, function(){
  // Do things
});
```

Thanks for the hand, Please let me know if there is something that I'm missing here.